# how can i remove the filters from the printer display generated by the printer friendly version for views drupal 7

Tags: views

Hope you all are fine. I am facing a difficulty in the drupal 7 module named printer friendly version. it is mainly made for the node print version. but I want to attach it with the views. so I created a view with page as a display. and attach the module with it by assigning the view name to its *Show link in system (non-content) pages*. It is working fine. but when it shows the print view it shows the filter textboxes and etc with it too. please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Kind regards.

Comment: Could you give me the link to the module you are using. This can be solved basically using a global variable from the module with overwriting your views template.

Comment: The module is printer PDF and email module you can chk it on google.

Comment: You can use some CSS to hide the unwanted page elements through printer specific style-sheet.